# Links in NavItems don't navigate to href url

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-bootstrap

I have Navdropdown items with the link inside of it in the Navdropdown. While I render it in the browser, everything works fine with the link, but I get the following warning in the console with method 1:

[image: ValidateDOMNesting(...) Warning]

due to the Link tag inside of the NavDropdown items. It's creating two nested anchor tags.

In the Method 2, I tried putting href instead of Link tag, but nav items don't navigate to href url. How do I resolve it??

Any help is appreciated.

Method 1:

```js
<NavDropdown>
      <NavDropdown.Item eventKey={1.1}>
        <Link to="/about#who_we_are">Who we are</Link>
      </NavDropdown.Item>
      <NavDropdown.Item eventKey={1.2}>
        <Link to="/about#how_we_work">How we work</Link>
      </NavDropdown.Item>
      <NavDropdown.Item eventKey={1.3}>
        <Link to="/about#certifications">Certifications</Link>
      </NavDropdown.Item>
      <NavDropdown.Item eventKey={1.4}>
        <Link to="/about#partners">Partners</Link>
      </NavDropdown.Item>
</NavDropdown>
```

Method 2:

```js
<NavDropdown.Item href="#/about#who_we_are" eventKey={1.1}>Who we are</NavDropdown.Item>
<NavDropdown.Item href="#/about#how_we_work" eventKey={1.2}>How we work</NavDropdown.Item>
<NavDropdown.Item href="#/about#certifications"eventKey={1.3}>Certifications</NavDropdown.Item>
<NavDropdown.Item href="#/about#partners"eventKey={1.4}>Partners</NavDropdown.Item>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://react-bootstrap.github.io/components/navbar/

Comment: @keikai I followed the documentation and did accordingly, but it didn't resolve my issues. The NavDropdown items doesn't navigate to the href url. With method 1 it's navigating to the about page with the given id, but it's showing the warnings as depicted in the figure . And, as per the documentation, i did the method 2 but it didn't work.

Comment: @proselenos, In method 2, can you try like ```<NavDropdown.Item componentClass={Link} href="/about#partners" to="/about#partners" eventKey={1.1}>Who we are</NavDropdown.Item>``` ??

Comment: @ManirajMurugan I tried that way also, but it shows the different url and didn't work so to match with the previous url i modified it by putting href="#/about#partners".

Let me try out with your edited comments.

Comment: @ManirajMurugan Got this warning when I tried the way you suggested. Warning: Invalid value for prop `componentclass` on <a> tag. Either remove it from the element, or pass a string or number value to keep it in the DOM.

Also, it's not working either way.